# integrate Facebook SDK and AdMob in IOS at a while

Tags: ios, facebook, admob

The ADmob SDK suggests me to change the other linker falgs of Buils settings to -Objc and facebook Sdk suggests me to change to  other linker flags to -Sqlite3.0 in order to complete the installation. In The Other Linker Flags i made both the -Objc and the -Sqlite3.0 but then the Admob Crashes. What should I do? I need both the FaceBook SDK and the ADMob in my APP.

Comment: What is the crash. Show the log and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

try adding -all_load to your Other Linker Flags section under the Build Settings.

Comment: The latest AdMob SDK will break if `-all_load` is included. If the FB SDK needs that flag, try using `-force_load` as demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254269/using-the-force-load-linker-flag-with-restkit-ios).