# Google Analytics and ShareKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-analytics, sharekit

I've been trying to integrate Sharekit to a project that already has google analytics.

I followed the installation guide on the sharekit git wiki which told me to include the 'other linker flags' "-ObjC" and "-all_load"

However when I try compiling I am getting duplicate symbol errors in google analytics, such as:

```
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OAServiceTicket.data in:
/Users/x3ro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-bgfudbwainndvsdmvtafsrwfryvz/Build/Intermediates/APPNAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.build/Objects-normal/i386/OAServiceTicket.o
/Users/x3ro/APPNAME/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-bgfudbwainndvsdmvtafsrwfryvz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libShareKit.a(OAServiceTicket.o)
```

Removing the flags solves these errors, however I know this isn't a good idea and I'll very likely run into issues down the line. Any help in getting the flags and both libraries to work together would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the linker flag "-force_load" with the path to Sharekit.

It look like something like this:

```
-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libRestKit.a
```

From Apple Documentation:

> -all_load forces the linker to load all object files from every archive it sees, even those without Objective-C code. -force_load is available in Xcode 3.2 and later. It allows finer grain control of archive loading. Each -force_load option must be followed by a path to an archive, and every object file in that archive will be loaded.

You can find others answers with this related post:
[Using the force_load linker flag with RestKit (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254269/using-the-force-load-linker-flag-with-restkit-ios)